# How do I display with React an Object I requested from the API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios

I'm trying to display different cards (Name, subcategory...) with each category from the API. But I cannot see what are the values in the API. For example I don't know what the ID is, or what if the category name is .title or .name So I cannot display it.

https://www.ifixit.com/api/2.0/categories

On the API I can see the name of the categories but no "ID", "NAME", "KEY"... So I don't know how to access that name when I try to display it.

```
componentDidMount() {
axios.get('/categories')
    .then(res => {
      const categories = res.data; //How do I get the "ID" from here?
      this.setState({categories: categories});
      })
}
```

Comment: Did you try to make a `console.log(res);` to see what's comin in the response?

Comment: Or use chrome development tools to stop at "const categories = res.data". So you can have a look what you get

Answer (score 0):

Chuck it in your console to view what it could be.

```js
componentDidMount() {
axios.get('/categories')
    .then(res => {
      const categories = res.data; //How do I get the "ID" from here?
      console.log({res, categories}) // Try this!
      this.setState({categories: categories});
      })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CDM would exist in your class, so you would also have a render() method:

```
render() {
  return (
    {Object.keys(this.state.categories).map((key) => {
      <p><span>{key}</span><span>{this.state.categories[key]}</span></p>
    }
  );
}
```

This will display a list of keys with their values from your data.

Answer (score 0):

After you assign the res.data to the state

```
axios.get('/categories')
      .then(res => { this.setState({ categories: res.data }) })
      .catch(err => { console.log(err) })
```

You can console.log "this.state.categories" and see is there any id/name details.

It depends on your database.

Edit:

As I checked your API, there is no id field. So you cannot access the id. 
But;

```
this.state.categories.Apparel
```

will give you the Apparel object. 
You can use a **unique** item in your object as a key.

Answer (score 0):

If you try an example code, like so:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const endpoint = 'https://www.ifixit.com/api/2.0/categories';

    fetch(endpoint).then(res => console.log(res.json()));
}
```

Open your console by clicking (F12), and you'll see that returns a `Promise`, but `ID` object doesn't exist.

[image]